# Woocommerce discount coupon for custom shipping fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried researching an answer for this problem now for the last 4 hours and I haven't managed to find an answer.

I have a custom fee added to my woocommerce checkout page. this is due to complicated delivery calculations which woocommerce shipping was unable to provide.

I now need to create a coupon to set this custom fee to zero if the coupon is entered.

This is setting my my custom fee

```
WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping', 'woocommerce'), $shipping_price );
```

This is what I need to achieve.

```
if($coupon_code == "this-string"){
$shipping_price = 0;
}
```

I need a way to check if the coupon code submitted is equal to "this-string" and if it is I need to set $shipping Fee to zero.

Please all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below Function will add a shipping fee to your woo-commerce Cart which adds to the checkout price afterwards.

```
// ADD SHIPPING COST

function woo_add_cart_fee() {

  WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping', 'woocommerce'), 100 );

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

If you want to apply a custom coupon to the shipping fee you could do something along the lines of this

```
// ADD SHIPPING COST

function woo_add_cart_fee() {

   $custom_coupon = $_GET["coupon_name"];

    if ($custom_coupon = 'discount_code_half') {

      WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping', 'woocommerce'), 100 );

    }elseif ($custom_coupon = 'discount_code_more_than_half') {

      WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping', 'woocommerce'), 50 );

    }elseif ($custom_coupon = 'discount_code_free') {

      WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping', 'woocommerce'), 0 );

    }else ( ! $custom_coupon) {

      WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping', 'woocommerce'), 200 );

    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_cart_fee' );
```

For this method to work you will need to have a coupon button to submit a coupon name to the cart page.

Either from the previous page or you could just have it submit to the same page it is on. Either way your page will have to refresh so you can use the

```
$custom_coupon = $_GET["coupon_name"];
```

Hope this answer helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons()` to get all the coupons applied to the cart. Then you can check if your coupon code is in that array. Something like this:

```
if(in_array($coupon_code, WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons())) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think you would want to do something when the code is applied, so the `woocommerce_applied_coupon` hook is relevant.

```
function so_46429329_applied_coupon( $coupon_code ) {
    if( $coupon_code == "this-string" ){
        $shipping_price = 0;
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Shipping', 'woocommerce'), $shipping_price );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'so_46429329_applied_coupon' );
```

The part that I haven't tested is whether this overrides an existing 'Shipping Fee' or if you need to find a way to remove that first.

Comment: Hi I tried your code. but it didn't change anything. I don't have to override it. if I can get it to discount the value of $shipping_price that will work to. do you have an idea of how I can do that?

Comment: I you can help me to create a regular coupon that discounts say.. R50 then i will be able the value of the $shipping_price in.

Comment: I had an idea, that's what I posted. :) It is untested... does look like there's a typo in the parameters `($cooupon_code)` should be `($coupon_code)`... otherwise the conditional IF will never be matched. See the edit. This should have shown up in your debug log if you have `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` enabled... which is usually a good idea when trying to develop something custom.

Comment: Thanks Helga :) will give it a try :)